# Jquery content Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/index.php

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll

How can i bring the two together, where

when u slide to a certain tag (Slower, Med, etc; you basically move to that particular box
that corresponds to it

never mind the drop down

need an example

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="2_files/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="2_files/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link href="2_files/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet">

   <style>
    #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; }
    .scroll-pane { overflow: auto; width: 99%; float:left; }
    .scroll-content { width: 2440px; float: left; }
    .scroll-content-item { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; font-size: 3em; line-height: 96px; text-align: center; }
    * html .scroll-content-item { display: inline; } /* IE6 float double margin bug */
    .scroll-bar-wrap { clear: left; padding: 0 4px 0 2px; margin: 0 -1px -1px -1px; }
    .scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider { background: none; border:0; height: 2em; margin: 0 auto;  }
    .scroll-bar-wrap .ui-handle-helper-parent { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
    .scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle { top:.2em; height: 1.5em; }
    .scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle .ui-icon { margin: -8px auto 0; position: relative; top: 50%; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
        <script>
    $(function() {
        var scrollPane = $( ".scroll-pane" ),
        var scrollContent = $( ".scroll-content" );
        var scrollbar = $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider({
            value:100,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 50,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                if ( scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width() ) {
                    scrollContent.css( "margin-left", Math.round(
                        ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width() )
                    ) + "px" );
                } else {
                    scrollContent.css( "margin-left", 0 );
                }
            }
        });
    });

        //append icon to handle
        var handleHelper = scrollbar.find( ".ui-slider-handle" )
        .mousedown(function() {
            scrollbar.width( handleHelper.width() );
        })
        .mouseup(function() {
            scrollbar.width( "100%" );
        })
        .append( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical'></span>" )
        .wrap( "<div class='ui-handle-helper-parent'></div>" ).parent();

        //change overflow to hidden now that slider handles the scrolling
        scrollPane.css( "overflow", "hidden" );

        //size scrollbar and handle proportionally to scroll distance
        function sizeScrollbar() {
            var remainder = scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width();
            var proportion = remainder / scrollContent.width();
            var handleSize = scrollPane.width() - ( proportion * scrollPane.width() );
            scrollbar.find( ".ui-slider-handle" ).css({
                width: handleSize,
                "margin-left": -handleSize / 2
            });
            handleHelper.width( "" ).width( scrollbar.width() - handleSize );
        }

        //reset slider value based on scroll content position
        function resetValue() {
            var remainder = scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width();
            var leftVal = scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ) === "auto" ? 0 :
                parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ) );
            var percentage = Math.round( leftVal / remainder * 100 );
            scrollbar.slider( "value", percentage );
        }

        //if the slider is 100% and window gets larger, reveal content
        function reflowContent() {
                var showing = scrollContent.width() + parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ), 10 );
                var gap = scrollPane.width() - showing;
                if ( gap > 0 ) {
                    scrollContent.css( "margin-left", parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ), 10 ) + gap );
                }
        }

        //change handle position on window resize
        $( window ).resize(function() {
            resetValue();
            sizeScrollbar();
            reflowContent();
        });
        //init scrollbar size
        setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div class="scroll-pane ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <div class="scroll-content">
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">1</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">2</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">3</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">4</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">5</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">6</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">7</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">8</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">9</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">10</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">11</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">12</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">13</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">14</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">15</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">16</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">17</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">18</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">19</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>Use a slider to manipulate the positioning of content on the page. In this case, it acts as a scrollbar with the potential to capture values if needed.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
</body></html>
```

Comment: i tried the above, but does not seem to be working, still messing with it

Comment: You should probably note that this is taken directly from the JQuery UI web site.

Answer (score 0):

do you can see the script (view code) in the demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll ?

just make litle modification to the scripts, just change to:

```
$(function() {
        var scrollPane = $( ".scroll-pane" ),
            scrollContent = $( ".scroll-content" );
        var scrollbar = $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider({
            value:100,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 50,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                if ( scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width() ) {
                    scrollContent.css( "margin-left", Math.round(
                        ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width() )
                    ) + "px" );
                } else {
                    scrollContent.css( "margin-left", 0 );
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

i have tried and it's works. then just make finishing touch for your need

Comment: try to make like on http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll first. copy all code there and try it (don't forget to call jquery.js, jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css)

then, just change all the script to initialize the scroller with the above code